# Call Web API in MVC app (No GET/POST/DELETE/UPDATE)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, http, sms

I am developing an MVC application that during order creation, will send an SMS to the registered phone number. The flow is:

- The user inputs personal details (including phone number) and order specific details
- The user receives an SMS with a code
- The user inputs the code to confirm the order

I want the controller to use a web api to send the code, just after the code is created in the controller action. I am using "clickatell" web api, where I can send an sms using this link:
`https://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?user=[USERNAME]&password=[PASSWORD]&api_id=[API ID]&to=[PHONE NUMBER]&text=[TXT MESSAGE]`

I do not need to get any information back, the API just sends the SMS when you visit the url. I need the controller to somehow visit the website (without showing it) or just send a message to it, to fire the SMS event.

I have tried to use the Http, uri and url classes but I cannot seem to find any methods to do what I want it to do. Is there a simple way to call the web api and make it send the SMS from the controller action?

Comment: have you tried `await new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://api.clickatell.com...")`? That should be able to do exactly what you want

Comment: I had not seen that way to do it, but you were right, it does exactly what I need, thank you!

Comment: great, I'll make it into answer even with some comments regarding response status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting a result from a WebAPI [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) can be used. It is recommended to also instantiated it only once per app rather then per use (you can check httpclient remarks in msdn) but for the example I'm gonna exclude that.

```
await new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://api.clickatell.com...")
```

This will return you [HttpResponseMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=netcore-3.1) and you might want to also be checking for the property `IsSuccessStatusCode` (or to directly call `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` which will throw an exception if you want to handle it that way) whether the request was successful or not, since the external service may not be available (or some other issue can also happen)